blender .fbx exports incorrectly animations with constraints
i uploaded a video to show my problem:
https://youtu.be/v1xl5Z_gMTQ
I have a problem exporting to an .fbx file in Blender.
I want to create a reload animation. In the scene there is a body with bones and the weapon with bones. The bones of the weapon are connected to the middle bones of the hand via a constraint (child of), so that the weapon follows the movement of the hand.
When I export the whole thing as .fbx to insert the animation into unity, the hand wobbles around the weapon during the animation. This looks extremely bad in the game. how could I solve this?
Many thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.
